# Involving data length as a decision variable in a optimization for parameter estimation

Tags: estimation, optimization

Consider I have $N$ historical data as outputs from a unknown time-varying system. Assuming within any small time interval $T$, the time-varying system can be approximated by a linear time invariant (LTI) system with n parameters.

In order to accurately determine all parameters, one solution is trying different time intervals and then find the group of parameters that gives the lowest prediction error.

I was wondering, it is possible to involve the time interval $T$ into the optimization as a decision variable, so we could find the best solution in one-go without looping?